# fetch key value pairs from object in sql BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, key-value, string-parsing

I need to parse the column message and fetch the key value pairs from the same object and i need to create new columns with the fetched data. The data looks like this:

```
{"segCode":"C002","segName":"Message Extras Test Segment Name", "segAssignType":"OFFER","offerStatic":"true","offerLoyLineItem":"1","offerCode":"654","offerLabel":"Sip Club: $1 Bagel","offerType":"SINGLE USE","offerDaysTilRwdStart":"","offerDaysTilRwdEnd":"","offerNbrVisitsToEarnRwd":"1","offerNbrDaysTilRwdExpire":"0","offerRwdLoadType":"ATL","offerEarnStartDt":"2023-05-18","offerEarnEndDt":"2023-05-28","offerRedeemStartDt":"2023-05-18","offerRedeemEndDt":"2023-05-28"}
```

desired output

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT9xD.png)

........
like all the keys should get converted to columns

Comment: You can use json functions like `JSON_VALUE(data, '$.segCode') AS segcode`.
see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions)